# How can I use \MakeOuterQuote{"} in combination with l3doc package?

Tags: csquotes, l3doc

Consider this TeX file

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
\enquote{hello} "hello"
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I want to use `"` as the quote characters. `csquotes` documentation states that `\MakeOuterQuote` can be used to do that, but for some reason it results in verbatim code instead.

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just use `\enquote` as in your example? It’s cleaner, less prone to errors, and with zero compatibility issues or package conflicts.

Comment: Because sometimes you get external texts, or something written by a collaborator, etc. and you don't want to go through your text replacing every instance of `"…"` with `\enquote{…}`. Yes, a regex could do it, but I find actual quotation marks easier to read, too.

Comment: Then how about using `\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}` instead? It’s still readable, and a redex expression can also replace `"` by `“` and `”` in the appropriate places. Alternatively, you can copy the external text into a word precessor (e.g. MS Word), and that word processor will then automatically do the replacement for you. LyX can do the same, too, I believe. Then you can copy it back into your LaTeX code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `"` as a shorthand for verbatim:

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\AtBeginDocument{\DeleteShortVerb\"}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
\enquote{hello} "hello"
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as a german I would never use `"` for quotes, that clashes with the shorthands setup by babel for german.

Comment: Luckily turning off those pesky (if well-meaning) babel shorthands is easy: `\usepackage[shorthands=off,ngerman]{babel}`. I never understood the appeal in the first place.

Comment: @Ingmar I know that, but  surprisingly I like to use the shorthands for hyphens and break commands like `""` and `"=`.

Comment: Yes, I get that. The comment was not for your benefit, obviously :-) It's safe to assume that you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `l3doc.cls` there are those 2 lines hard coded

```
\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \MakeShortVerb \"
    \MakeShortVerb \|
  }
```

As such, the 2 characters `"` and `|` will be made into short-verb characters. <sub>(remark: documentation of `\MakeShortVerb` can be found in `texdoc doc`. The `fancyvrb` package that `l3doc` uses has a similar command, `\DefineShortVerb`)</sub>

Any attempt to redefine `"` in the preamble will be overridden, and `csquotes` does not support defining them in the document itself.

I can find a way to override the behavior, but it's rather ugly:

```
\RemoveFromHook{begindocument}[l3doc]
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

Side note, `\RemoveFromHook` is available in a sufficiently new LaTeX version. In older versions you might need to manipulate `\@begindocumenthook` manually...?

At least in the current version it won't have any unexpected consequence, as can be shown by executing

```
\ShowHook{begindocument}
```

which shows that the 2 commands above are the only ones that gets removed by the `\RemoveFromHook`.

(which means that in some future versions l3doc might do something-else in `\AtBeginDocument` and the code above would break. Use with care.)

(although you might want to manually `\MakeShortVerb \|` afterwards.)